# Как мне подключить созданную БД к сайту

Tags: mysql, linux, база-данных

Пытаюсь подключить MySQL в консоли Ubuntu (Linux) в файле с сайтом на пхп (домашнее задание, а не рабочий проект).

Выдает ошибку когда захожу на сайт (вбиваю IP в браузер)

> Попытка подключения не удалась.

Это похоже он не может подключиться к данным что я ввел, но они корректные, и БД с таким именем создана, в чем может быть проблема?

Снизу часть кода

```
<?php

  // Database access definition
  $dbname     = "abook";
  $dbserver   = "192.168.56.101";
  $dbuser     = "abook";
  $dbpass     = "asdffdsA1";
  $dbcnx = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$dbcnx)
{
echo "<p>Попытка подключения не удалась MySQL</p>";
exit();
}
if (!mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbcnx) )
{
echo "<p>Выбрать базу данных невозможно</p>";
exit();
}
$ver = mysql_query("SELECT VERSION()");
if(!$ver)
{
echo "<p>Запрос неверен</p>";
exit();
}
echo mysql_result($ver, 0);
  // Define table prefix
  $table_prefix = "ab_";

  // Don't display groups
  $nogroups = false;

  // Disable all "edit/create" actions.
  $read_only  = false;
```

Comment: БД на каком то хостинге или спец. сервис у вас ? Мне кажется у вас хостин (ресурс кто дал бд) блочит подклчючение таким способом. Попробуйте вывести код ошибки при подключение что отдает и там может быть ответ будет вам. 

mysql_connect "Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0."

У вас пхп какой версии, может уже просто не поддерживает эту функцию сайт с какого вы пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Какая версия PHP? Попробуйте mysqli писать вместо mysql.

Привожу пример рабочего кода:

```
<?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASSWORD", "DBNAME", "DBPORT"); //подключаемся
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SQL-ЗАПРОС"); //выполняем любой запрос

    //ну и гуглим команды mysqli, к примеру если запрос был SELECT и
    //результат - несколько строк, то получаем их следующим образом:
    $result = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { //пробегаемся по каждой строке
        $result[] = $row; //записываем значение в массив
    }

    print_r($result); //тестируем - выводим массив

    //если запрос не выводящий результат, такой как INSERT, то что то вроде
    if (!$query) {
        echo 'Не удалось выполнить запрос';
    } else {
        echo 'Запрос выполнен успешно';
    }        
?>
```

Потом уже, когда всё вышеописанное получится, можно углубляться и делать более грамотно, с выводом ошибок, выводом успешного результата в формате API (например JSON) и так далее. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

6 возможностей:

1. Или **IP** неправильное,
2. или MySQL сервер во время вашего тестирования **не работал**,
3. или сервер работает на **нестандартном порте** (т.е. не на 3306) - тогда нужно его добавить к IP адресу, например `$dbserver   = "192.168.56.101:8888";`
4. или **имя** неправильное,
5. или **пароль** неправильный,
6. или общие проблемы **с подключением к компьютеру-серверу** (хардвер, TCP/IP софтвер — на пути от вашего компютера к серверу).